# Solspace Favorites for members only?

Tags: solspace

I guess I should have read that properly but is there no way to enable Solspace Favorites to work with cookies only – not requiring membership??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it only works for logged in members. For a cookie-based favorite-type functionality you can use [Shortlist](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shortlist).

Answer (score 0):

Try [remember-me](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/remember-me)  - its free and function inside is enough for build favorite functions.